# Code for ball gets the error - ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red') TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'color'

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm making a game called Bounce and after finishing the main part of the game, I added code to delay the game start, add a 'game over' sign, accelerate the ball, and record the player's score. This is the code after the extra code.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, score, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.score = score
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False
    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                self.x += self.paddle.x
                self.score.hit()
                return True
            return False
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 1
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.started = False
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<Button-1>', self.start_game)
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0
    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2
    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2
    def start_game(self, evt):
        self.started = True
class Score:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.score = 0
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_text(450, 10, text=self.score, \
                fill=color)
    def hit(self):
        self.score += 1
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.id, text=self.score)
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Bounce")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost" , 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()
score = Score(canvas, 'green')
paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')
game_over_text = canvas.create_text(250, 200, text='GAME OVER', \
        state='hidden')
while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False and paddle.started == True:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    if ball.hit_bottom == True:
        time.sleep(1)
        canvas.itemconfig(game_over_text, state='normal')
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

However, after adding those details, I'm recieving this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\WordPressGames\Bounce\bounce.py", line 81, in <module>
    ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'color'
```

I've double-checked the code again to see if I made any typos and I don't see any. Is there an error I just haven't noticed?

Comment: The object clearly requires four parameters in addition to `self`: canvas, paddle, score, and color. You're giving it three.

Comment: So give the 4 parameters to all other classes?

Comment: This works !  if you certainly give 'score' parameter also. Try this: 
```ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, score, 'red')```

Comment: Ok. I'll try both of them later today. Thanks!

Comment: _"So give the 4 parameters to all other classes"_ I don't know exactly what you mean by that. This specific error is because you are giving the wrong number of parameters to the `Ball` class.

Comment: Never mind! I got it working!